# models.FileField(blank=False): form is valid even if I don't choose file during update

Tags: django

**Django 1.11.2**

This view is called via **AJAX**. It may be important.

In the model I used blank=False. In DeleteOldFileMixin I have put a breakpoint (please the comment in the code below where it is).

I run Django, try to update an existing UserFile object. The update form appears. But i don't select any file, I just press "Submit". And I occur at breakpoint.

The breakpoint is inside form_valid method. This means that form is already cleaned.

My code works incorrectly: it deletes an old file without substituting it with a new one.

But if I use blank=False, why the form should be valid? If the form could intercept this empty field, I'd be glad.

Could you give me a kick here?

```
class UserFile(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    user_file = models.FileField(blank=False,
                                 verbose_name=_("file"),
                                 max_length=255,
                                 upload_to=get_file_path)


class FileForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserFile
        exclude = []


class DeleteOldFileMixin(ModelFormMixin):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        old_file_name = form.initial.get('user_file').name # Breakpoint
        try:
            os.remove("{}/{}".format(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, old_file_name))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass # Do nothing.

        return super(DeleteOldFileMixin, self).form_valid(form)


class FileUpdate(DeleteOldFileMixin,
                 UpdateView):
    model = UserFile
    form_class = FileForm
```

**ADDED LATER:**

ValueError risen:

```
class DeleteOldFileMixin(ModelFormMixin):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        raise ValueError(self.request.FILES)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 56, in dispatch
    return super(LoginRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 92, in dispatch
    return super(PermissionRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_2/photoarchive/general/view_mixins.py", line 61, in dispatch
    **kwargs);
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 240, in post
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/venv/photoarchive/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 183, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/photoarchive_2/photoarchive/general/view_mixins.py", line 113, in form_valid
    raise ValueError(self.request.FILES)
ValueError: <MultiValueDict: {}>
[27/Jun/2017 14:39:22] "POST /files/7/update/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20475
```

Comment: Above your breakpoint, insert `raise ValueError(self.request.FILES)`. Then show the exception.

Comment: Melvyn, I added it to the initial post.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with the actual code you have posted above?
 The traceback has a lot of code (e.g. `BaseUpdateView`, `LoginRequiredMixin`) that you have not shown. Can you reproduce the problem if you do not submit with AJAX? If not, then show the code you are using to submit the request.

Comment: BaseUpdateView is a superclass of UpdateView. LoginRequiredMixin doesn't relate here at all. I can exclude LoginRequiredMixin but it is not about the issue at all. Anyway, the two mentioned classes is not my code. It is a part of django.